# Modify the date format for a search result items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search

Modify the date format for a search result items inside the callouts in a  ent.search site .
currently  we are having the  SP  default date format , like mm/dd/yyyy, i need to change it to  a  format like 23-Mar-2017 ,  ie dd-mmm-YYYY. 
How to achieve this?

[image: modify-the-date-format]

Answer (score 1):

We need to updated the date format in the display Tempaltes.

Copy/paste a variable in the template, something like:

```
var modifiedDate =  $getItemValue(ctx, "ModifiedOWSDATE");
modifiedDate.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);
And use that variable instead:

<p>_#= modifiedDate =#_</p>
If creating a new custom Value Renderer etc is not an option for formatting the date (The default pattern used by Search.ClientControls isLongDatePattern I think). One could always create a Date variable, and do as fit:

Example:

<p>_#= new Date(modifiedDate["inputValue"]).toLocaleString() =#_</p>
```

please check the sharepoint.stackexchange post
[Changing date format in display templates for SharePoint 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690901/changing-date-format-in-display-templates-for-sharepoint-2013)

It may help you..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating Dateformat yourself or loading moment.js...

SharePoint adds a `String.format` function
so you can use:

```
String.format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}',new Date('2015-10-30T05:00:00Z'));
```

Note: String.format is defined in `msajaxbundle.js`, loaded even before most of the JavaScript files so safe to use without SOD requirements or anything.
It was modelled after the C# and VB implementations, 
so [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Format_Params) applies
(*for the major part; it does not do the alignment stuff as that makes no sense in HTML*)

[MSDN String.format() Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
String.format("{0:i}",new Date());  outputs: Wed Oct 07 2015 20:39:54 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
String.format("{0:F}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39:54
String.format("{0:f}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39
String.format("{0:D}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015
String.format("{0:s}",new Date());  outputs: 2015-10-07T20:39:54
String.format("{0:d}",new Date());  outputs: 10/07/2015
String.format("{0:dd}",new Date());  outputs: 07
String.format("{0:ddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wed
String.format("{0:dddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday
String.format("{0:m}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:M}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:MM}",new Date());  outputs: 10
String.format("{0:MMM}",new Date());  outputs: Oct
String.format("{0:MMMM}",new Date());  outputs: October
String.format("{0:Y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:yy}",new Date());  outputs: 15
String.format("{0:yyyy}",new Date());  outputs: 2015
String.format("{0:gg}",new Date());  outputs: A.D.
String.format("{0:T}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39:54
String.format("{0:t}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39
String.format("{0:HH}",new Date());  outputs: 20
String.format("{0:mm}",new Date());  outputs: 39
String.format("{0:ss}",new Date());  outputs: 54
```

J5 iJS string format top20

Comment: Danny, where will I update the code string.format() ? if you please can elaborate a little bit....

Comment: In the Search DisplayTemplate the other answer pointed you to

Comment: {0:yyyy-MM-dd} should also work